# Linq solution for list of object?

Tags: c#, linq

```
int count = 0;
foreach (Treatment treatment in DeclarationContent.Treatments)
{
    if (treatment.TreatmentNumber == treatmentNumber)
        break;

    count++;
}
```

I want to have a Linq statement for above foreach statement.

Comment: -1 Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before you ask a question. (Hint: try to make a solution by looking at tutorials etc. and when you are stuck, ask a question here) :-)

Comment: @ mBotros index of object in the collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var count = DeclarationContent.Treatments
                              .TakeWhile(t => t.TreatmentNumber != treatmentNumber)
                              .Count();
```

This uses `TakeWhile` to only count all the treatments until some treatmentnumber is equal to your argument. You can't use `.Where()` here (as other answers state) because that will not be the same semantic as your `foreach` has (however, it may be what you want ;-) )

**Updated:** 
I see you want the index, in that case you can also do like this (and `.Treatment` instead of `.Index` if you want the `Treatment` object.):

```
var index = DeclarationContent.Treatments
                              .Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, Treatment = t })
                              .First(pair => pair.Treatment.TreatmentNumber == treatmentNumber)
                              .Index;
```

**Note:**
You might have to replace `DeclarationContent.Treatments` with `DeclarationContent.Treatments.Cast<Treatment>()` as noted in a comment.

Comment: +1: However I think you'll have to cast `t` before using it, I think (as given in the title, and suggested by the `foreach` usage, that `DeclarationContent.Treatments` is a list of `object`

Comment: +1 cause it's the only solution that behaves exactly as the given foreach statement.

Comment: @Binary Thanks :) It´s added now.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = DeclarationContent.Treatments.TakeWhile(treatment.TreatmentNumber == treatmentNumber).Count();
```